# Removing node from doubly linked list gives segmentation fault - C

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I have written a program that can can add char characters to the start of a doubly linked list. Now once I have this list, the aim of my program is to remove certain char character(s) from the list entirely. For example (using curly brackets only for representative purposes): if list consists of **{ a, b, b, a, c }**, then my program can remove all "b" from the list to make it **{ a, a, c}**. Moreover, if my list is **{b, a, c, a}** or **{a, c, a, b}** and if I want to remove "b" then the program works fine for both cases and gives me **{a, c, a}**.

But there's a number of issues (for all cases assume I want to remove "b"):

1. if my list is **{b, a, b, a, c}** ("b" at front and somewhere in middle), I get segmentation fault (I think it has to do with using cursor in the while loop, but I don't know why exactly and how to fix it)
2. if my list is **{a, b, b, a, c, b}** ("b" in middle and at last) then output gives me weird symbols (I'm assuming its a memory fault, don't know why)

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct list
{
   int data;
   struct list* next;
   struct list* prev;
};

struct list* head; // global variable - pointer to head node of list.
struct list* last; // global variable - pointer to last node of list

//Creates a new list and returns pointer to it.
struct list* GetNewNode(char x)
{
   struct list* newNode
       = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
   newNode->data = x;
   newNode->prev = NULL;
   newNode->next = NULL;
   return newNode;
}

//Inserts a list at head of doubly linked list
void InsertAtHead(char x)
{
   struct list* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
   if(head == NULL)
   {
       head = newNode;
       return;
   }

   head->prev = newNode;
   newNode->next = head;
   head = newNode;
   struct list* temp = head;

   while (temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next;
   last = temp;
}

void remove_element (char character)
{
   struct list * cursor, *previous, *store_el;
   //int boolean = 0;

   if (head == NULL) return;
   else
   {
       cursor = head;
       while(cursor != NULL)
       {
           if (cursor->data == character)
           {
               if (cursor->prev == NULL)
               {
                  // printf("deleting from front\n");
                   previous = head;
                   head = head->next;
                   head->prev = NULL;
                   //boolean = 1;
                   //free(previous);
               }
               if (cursor->next == NULL)
               {
                   //printf("deleting from back\n");
                   previous = last;
                   last = last->prev;
                   last->next = NULL;
                   //boolean = 1;
                   //free(previous);
               }
               else
               {
                  // printf("deleting from middle\n");
                   previous = cursor;
                   cursor = cursor->next;
                   cursor->prev = previous->prev;
                   store_el = previous->prev;
                   store_el->next = cursor;
                   cursor = head;

               }
               free(previous);
               //printf("head data = %c\n", cursor->data);
           }
           cursor = cursor->next;
       }
   }
}

//Prints all the elements in linked list in forward traversal order
void Print()
{
   struct list* temp = head;
   printf("Forward: ");
   while(temp != NULL)
   {
       printf("%c ",temp->data);
       temp = temp->next;
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

   char character;
   /*Driver code to test the implementation*/
   head = NULL; // empty list. set head as NULL.

   // Calling an Insert and printing list before and after deletion of character
   InsertAtHead('c');
   InsertAtHead('a');
   InsertAtHead('b');
   InsertAtHead('b');
   InsertAtHead('a');
   Print();
   printf("After deletion:\n");
   remove_element ('b');
   Print();
}
```

Comment: 7-8 hours is a long time to look for an issue like this without finding anything.  How exactly have you approached it?  Are you just guessing?  Or are you using a debugger?

Comment: One thing I notice immediately is that when you remove an element at the head, your `cursor` is not modified.  You will replace the head, and free the old one (stored in both `cursor` and `previous`), then go on to use an invalid pointer with `cursor = cursor->next`.  You do something similar with deleting an item at the tail.  When you remove an element, you should _not_ advance the cursor by following the `next` pointer.  Instead, you already know what the next will be when changing linkage (as you clearly handle when deleting in the middle of the list), so you just need to update it.

Comment: I mis-typed that, I have now correctly edited my post. I meant to say I spent 7-8 hours trying to finish the code, but it still took 3 hours or so to find the issues without any luck. I use a pen and paper to try to visualize the doubly linked lists and to get familiar with the data structure (I've gone through 15 pages or something). I kept trying different ways to solve the problem, but without any luck. I unfortunately don't know how to use a debugger, perhaps you could link me to good resources that teach how to use a debugger. Thank you!

Comment: Did you read my comment regarding the actual issue?  (or one issue, at least)

Comment: Yes I read your comment and it makes sense. Unfortunately, it's too late here where I live so I need to sign off. Thank you so much for your comment, I will try implementing a solution later tomorrow, and report here.

Comment: Using a debugger: step 1, choose a debugger to use.  step 2, look for documentation and / or tutorials for that debugger on line.  We generally do not do software recommendations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* 
*I changed the name of your variable 'last' to 'tail'
*I removed the code at the end of your InsertAtHead function
*I added "tail = newNode;"
*I changed the name of your variable 'previous' to 'garbage'
*I removed your variable 'store_el' completely.
*I could have changed the whole code in your remove element function because the 3 cases are unnecessary but anyway.
*/
//Inserts a list at head of doubly linked list
void InsertAtHead(char x){
    struct list* newNode = GetNewNode(x);

    if (head == NULL){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        return;
    }

    head->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

void remove_element (char character){
    struct list * cursor,  *garbage;

    cursor = head;
    while(cursor != NULL){
        if (cursor->data == character){
                garbage = cursor;

                if (cursor->prev == NULL){
                    head = head->next;
                    If (head!=NULL) head->prev = NULL;
                    cursor=head;
                }else if (cursor->next == NULL){
                    tail = tail->prev;
                    tail->next = NULL;
                    cursor=NULL;
                }else{
                    garbage->prev->next = garbage->next;
                    garbage->next->prev = garbage->prev;
                    cursor=cursor->next;
                }

                free(garbage);
        } else cursor=cursor->next;
    }
}
```

Try it now.

The problem with your code was that you were using the memory you freed.

```
/*
*cursor and previous point to the same memory address
*you free the memory that the variable previous points so the cursor points to that freed memory 
*when you save the next address to the cursor using that freed memory you create an undefined behaviour (your code may work or may not)
*/
cursor = head;
        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
            if (cursor->data == character)
            {
                if (cursor->prev == NULL)
                {
                    previous = head;
                    head = head->next;
                    head->prev = NULL;
                    free(previous);
...
cursor=cursor->next;
```

The Improved Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//The type of your variable data was wrong. I changed it to char
struct list{
    char data;
    struct list *prev, *next
};

void remove_element (char character){
    struct list * cursor,  *garbage;

    cursor = head;
    while(cursor != NULL){
        if (cursor->data == character){
                garbage = cursor;

                if (garbage->prev!=NULL ) garbage->prev->next = garbage->next;
                if (garbage->next!=NULL ) garbage->next->prev = garbage->prev;
                cursor=cursor->next;

                if (head==garbage) head=cursor;
                //Basically the tail variable has no use for your current program.
                //if (tail==garbage) tail=garbage->prev;

                free(garbage);
        } else cursor=cursor->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work and makes a lot of sense too! But I am wondering how to change my code so that the 3 cases inside the "remove_element" function are not needed at all, but my program works as intended too. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the cursor

```
cursor = head;
```

after you delete from the front.

Answer (score 0):

Ellothere I think the problem in your program is you are assigning the address of the node in previous but you are not freeing it side by side.

```
       if (cursor->prev == NULL)
       {
          // printf("deleting from front\n");
           previous = head;
           head = head->next;
           head->prev = NULL;
           //boolean = 1;
           //free(previous);
       }
       if (cursor->next == NULL)
       {
           //printf("deleting from back\n");
           previous = last;
           last = last->prev;
           last->next = NULL;
           //boolean = 1;
           //free(previous);
       }
```

Here you are storing node but freeing it at the end and then there are 2 if statements here then what is happening is both 'b' in {a b b a c} are next to each other so first *previous* **variable** is storing the address of first 'b' then it is storing the address of *next* 'b' and it is just freeing that 'b' and that one 'b' remains there . In short you should free the node side- by - side. I did this small change and it works fine .

```
if (cursor->prev == NULL)
               {
                  // printf("deleting from front\n");
                   previous = head;
                   head = head->next;
                   head->prev = NULL;
                   free(previous);
                   //boolean = 1;
                   //free(previous);
               }
               if (cursor->next == NULL)
               {
                   //printf("deleting from back\n");
                   previous = last;
                   last = last->prev;
                   last->next = NULL;
                   free(previous);
                   //boolean = 1;
                   //free(previous);
               }
               else
               {
                  // printf("deleting from middle\n");
                   previous = cursor;
                   cursor = cursor->next;
                   cursor->prev = previous->prev;
                   store_el = previous->prev;
                   store_el->next = cursor;
                   cursor = head;

               }
```

I have just added a ***free*** function in both *if* statements.